# Android Table Layout with 5x5 dimension

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-widget

I'm still new in android programming, what I'm trying to do is, I want to create 5x5 dimension TableLayout. I know this can be done by using GridView BaseAdapter suing Inflate service. But for this one i try to apply using table layout. Below is the code. I create new instance of TableLayout, and new instance of Table row. On each table row, I created instance of 5 TextView. But once I open in emulator or in my phone, there is no TableRow created, it just empty blank Table Layout. Also there is no exception was thrown.

GridView navIcon = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        navIcon.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

```
    navIcon.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

            if (position==0){   

                try{
                    TableLayout calgrid = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridtable);                       
                    Context ctxt = v.getContext();
                    TextView[] tView = new TextView[25];    
                    calgrid = new TableLayout(ctxt);
                    int dip = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,(float) 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    int counter=1;
                    TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[5];
                    for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                        tr[j] = new TableRow(ctxt);
                        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){                               
                            tView[i] = new TextView(ctxt);

                            tView[i].setText(String.valueOf(counter));      
                            tView[i].setTextSize(15);
                            counter+=1;
                            tView[i].setWidth(50 * dip);
                            tView[i].setPadding(20*dip, 0, 0, 0);
                            tView[i].setTextColor(Color.rgb( 100, 200, 200));                               
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tView["+i+"] value " + String.valueOf(tView[i].getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     

                            tr[j].addView(tView[i], 50, 50);                            
                        }
                        calgrid.addView(tr[j]);                         
                    }                                           
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in activity", e);  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                                           
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is a mistake to do `calgrid = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridtable);` and then `calgrid = new TableLayout(ctxt);`, which basically says find this view now assign this variable to something completely different. Remove the second statement and it will load the table from xml which is what you want.

Second, I think it would be a good idea to simplify things for yourself because there is a lot going on here. Instead of doing all this work inside an `onClick` listener, do it in the `onCreate` method itself. Also, you seem to be using the Context from the GridView, which seems odd. Perhaps if you posted your xml layout file it could help explain what you are trying to do?

There is also a problem with indices in the array of TextViews, as `tView[i]` will only assign items up to 5 but the array contains 25 items. Try using `tView[(j*5)+i]` instead. I don't think this is causing your problems but just make sure you are assigning your items correctly.

Here is an example of how to do something along the lines of what you want

```
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);

    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridtable);
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            TextView tView = new TextView(this);

            tView.setText("TEXT" + String.valueOf((j * 5) + i + 1));
            tView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tr.addView(tView);
        }
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

and `grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridtable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</TableLayout>
```

Once you get it working in the activity itself you can try to put it inside a listener attached to a GridView. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I remain my existing code, It's working after I remove calgrid = new TableLayout(ctxt); from my code, just because this one line of code it's not working. Next time I will be careful when instantiate an object. I spend my whole day yesterday to figure what's wrong. Your advice really helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept this answer if it answers your question.